# Проблемы с onclick в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, слайдер

Есть код простого слайдера.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");

  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_div">
  <div class="slideshow_container">
    <div class="myslides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1/3</div>
      <img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="myslides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2/3</div>
      <img src="img/slide2.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="myslides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3/3</div>
      <img src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Хотелось бы убрать из html-разметки вызов onclick на span.dot. Попробовал написать такую функцию, но она не приводит ни к какому результату:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
    for (var i=0;i<dots.length;i++) {
        dots[i].onclick = currentSlide(i+1);
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле все просто. Вы присваиваете onclick вычисленное значение функции, то есть вы вызываете функцию, вместо того, чтобы присвоить callback.

Правильно код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
    for (var i=0;i<dots.length;i++) {
        dots[i].onclick = function(idx){
            return function(){
                currentSlide(idx+1);
            }
        }(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это почти сработало. Появился клик, но по какой-то причине аргумент функции currentSlide  всегда остается равным единице, и нажатие на любую dot приводит к первому слайду

Comment: @joestalin14 поправил

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А как это работает?

Comment: @joestalin14 в предыдущем варианте мы передавали функцию, которая использовала одно и то же значение переменной для всех callback. В последнем варианте я обернул одну функцию в другую, тем самым сформировав отдельную локальную переменную для каждого вызова callback. Для более углубленного изучение нужно понимать как работает Javascript виртуальная машина